# CakePHP application automatically logs out within few seconds

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have used CakePHP in my application. But it has a weird problem. Some times a user is
being automatically logged out after within few secs. How to stop this auto log out?

I have set below codes in my app/config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

Comment: Does it happen from time to time or always? does it happens with a specific user or any user?

Comment: @api55:- It happens for sometime not always .

Comment: try to check your actions maybe you are destroying the session or cookies some where.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set session time out in the **app/Config/core.php**.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
                'timeout' => 20,//20minutes
                'autoRegenerate' => true,//resets session on activity
                'cookieTimeout' => 1440
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. At that time the random loggin out stopped after I fixed a 404 request on one of the images called by a .css file. By that time I was running CakePHP 1.3 though and I have never had a similar issue on CakePHP 2.0

Its commentend on the answers for this question [CakePHP session/auth logging out intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573550/cakephp-session-auth-logging-out-intermittently) that:

> The 404 request apparently can reset the Cake Auth/Session, not a generic PHP issue