# auth session destroyed while working with firebug

Tags: cakephp, firebug, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I am using CakePHP - 2.1

**Whenever I tried to work with firebug to trace ajax requests in the website, then suddenly my Auth Session destroyed. It is not sometime but always.**

To work with firebug, I just have to open the firebug before entering the credentials, then it works fine until I closes the firebug panel. I also tried with CakePHP-2.2.1 but the same result happened.

I am using Firefox 14.0.1

Is this a functionality implemented in latest version of CakePHP or is there any option of enable/disable so that I can use firebug anytime during my development work on the site, without re-entering the login credentials?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573550/cakephp-session-auth-logging-out-intermittently
it is also representing the same problem. May be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. You can set the `CakePHP` security level from `HIGH` to `MEDIUM`. You will find this code in `\app\Config\core.php`.

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'Medium');
```